# set up Delayed_job with monit monitoring tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, monitoring, delayed-job, monit

I am deploying Rubyonrails web app with ruby 1.9.2p280, rubyonrails 3.07 with apache passenger and delayed_job as background job.

I would like to monitor my passenger as well as delayed_job background job.

I could not find any step by step guide.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Based on my experience with DelayedJob, I recommend not using it unless you have to. If you're deploying to Heroku, use it because that's what's available. If you are able to set up your own cron jobs, however, then just write records to a table with details about what needs to be done, and create a module or class method that performs the pending actions.  Set up a cron job to read the table and execute the pending actions: `rails runner "SomeModule.some_method"`. I'm not sure what that means for the monitoring that you want, but you'll probably be better off having not used DelayedJob.

Comment: I would like to monitor my webserver process and delayed_job process. If they hit a certain point of memory or percentage of cpu time then they should be restarted automatically. Memory consumption by delayed_job and passenger grow over time and may eventually have high swap usage, causing them to become unresponsive.

Comment: @Steve Why should the class that one self writes handle it better than `delayed_job`? Why use the hours to develop instead of using what's there and widely used?!

Comment: @YoLudke because it actually does very little for you that's useful, and some of what it does do for you, it does in a way that can get you into trouble and cost you many more hours in debugging time than the time it takes to write it yourself -- in my opinion, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following .monitrc files as mention below and run the command `monit reload` to load the configuration.

**/etc/monit/web.monitrc**

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
  if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
  if totalmem > 300.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
  if children > 250 then alert
  if failed port 80 with timeout 10 seconds then restart
  if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
  mode manual
  group web
```

**/etc/monit/delayed_job.monitrc**

```
check process delayed_job with pidfile /mnt/<project>/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/delayed_job_start"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/delayed_job_stop"
  mode manual
  group delayed_job
```

**/usr/bin/delayed_job_start**

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /mnt/<project> && RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/delayed_job start
```

Comment: Sorry am asking with apache, not nginx. I can not find any help about for example: if cpu usage > 80% for 5 cycles then restart. what does it mean 5 cycles ?

Comment: Have updated the answer with apache. Number of cycles = no of times the monit checks for the status. When monit finds that the CPU usage of apache process is greater than 85 % for 5 consecutive checks, it will restart the apache.

Comment: Just one more real quick question, where i can not find the pid file of apache2? i don't have /var/run/apache2.pid in my system. what's wrong ? when using monit do I have to stop apache2 daemon from my system and let monit start it instead ? thanks you very much for ur help